# Is it worth having a community wiki question about blockchain explorers?

Tags: discussion

Blockchain explorers will come and go, but I think it may be worth having a canonical question with a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer which lists those that are live. We can encourage people to edit the answer if they spot a site that is down for a few days. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I would actually love this.  As I currently don't understand most of the functionalities of a blockchain explorer.

Answer (score 4):

Great idea, I have started a community wiki for this purpose as the answer to [What Ethereum blockchain explorers exist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist)

Please improve!

Answer (score 2):

Yes I think so, and answers that mention explorers can point to the wiki instead of a single explorer.